# $10$ different balls are to be placed in $4$ distinct boxes at random. The probability that two of these boxes contain exactly $2$ and $3$ balls is:-

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

If $10$ different balls are to be placed in $4$ distinct boxes at random, then the probability that two of these boxes containing exactly $2$ and $3$ balls is:-
Solving:- total ways

$$n(s)=4^{10}$$

( As, for each ball, 4 boxes to select from)

Probability

$${\frac{{4\choose2}.{10\choose5}.{5\choose3}.2.2^5}{4^{10}}} = \frac{945}{2^{10}}$$

(As for Rest balls 2 boxes to select from)

Way-2:-

making Pairs $(2,3,5,0);(2,3,4,1); (2,3,2,3)$

$$n(E)= {\frac{10!×4!}{2!3!5!0!}}+{\frac{10!×4!}{2!3!4!1!}} +{\frac{10!×4!}{2!3!2!3!×2!2!}}$$

Hence, probability equals

$${\frac{n(E)}{n(S)}}={\frac{945×17}{2^{15}}}$$

Here, the correct answer is from Way-2 and answer of way-1 is incorrect but can anyone please explain in detail what is wrong in way-1 as, we are getting wrong answer from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first solution is prone to double counting - the usual suspect. Consider the following cases.

Let's label the boxes A, B, C, and D, and the balls ${b_1, b_2 ... b_{10}}$

**CASE $\mathbf 1$**

You pick A and B as the two *chosen* boxes. A gets two balls - $b_1$ and $b_2$. B gets three balls $b_3$, $b_4$ and $b_5$.

The remaining $5$ balls are free to go into C or D - no restrictions. So, $b_6$ and $b_7$ go to C. and $b_8$, $b_9$ and $b_{10}$ go to D.

**CASE $\mathbf 2$**

You pick C and D as the two *chosen* boxes. C gets two balls - $b_6$ and $b_7$. D gets three balls $b_8$, $b_9$ and $b_{10}$.

The remaining $5$ balls are free to go into A or B. So, $b_1$ and $b_2$ go to A. And $b_3$, $b_4$ and $b_5$ go to B.

The solution counts these as two distinct cases. When, in fact, they are one and the same.

Meaning, the number of ways is over-estimated. And so is the probability.